# How to create a list of groupchats

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

I have a firebase document structured as chats/groupchatID/messages/message where GroupchatId is the combination of 2 user Ids such as ID2ID1 or ID1ID2. I have a page that has a listview builder that needs a snapshot of the other user to create the listview for them and to open the groupchats

I currently display the list by displaying all users such as

```
child: FutureBuilder(
          future: FirebaseFirestore.instance
              .collection('users')
              .where(
                'uid',
                isNotEqualTo: FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid,
              )
              .orderBy('uid', descending: true)
              .get(),
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
```

Im trying to now change it to show only the groupchats that exist in the firebase that the user is in. How can I return only thr groupchats the current user is in like is there a way I can check for substrings in firebase and then would I have to do another firebase query for each list tile to get the data for that user as that seems inefficient

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to check the substring for both users, as Firestore queries can only do prefix filtering: so only strings starting with a certain substring.

The solution is to include an array of the participant UIDs inside the document as an array field, and then filter on that with something like:

```
.where(
  'participantUIDs',
  arrayContains: FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid,
)
```

Comment: Oh right I see! im too used to sql with wildcards and such and just assumed that would be a thing. Ill give this a go

Comment: Do you know if theres a way for instance if the current user id randomly appears in index 0 or 1 how to always select the array index that does not equal the current user?

Comment: I'm not sure I follow that problem. But it also sounds like a different question, so I recommend posting it as such with its own [minimal repro](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).